# What is ArcGIS Layer basically?

Tags: maps, arcgis

Hi I am recently trying to build ArcGIS applications, when i tried one i came across creating a layer online and importing onto our current map, the thing is, i was thinking it would be more like this: the map would be the canvas and whatever data we need will be on a plastic sheet which we can place upon the canvas for visualization, and remove it upon our need, but recently i tried to create my own 3d layer data and there were 2d points coming out when i asked someone they said the layer is not like the plastic sheet but  table where you store the data and later take it as a reference to draw them in whatever shapes you want, can anyone shed more light into this??

Answer (score 0):

There are some things that I think are important to clear up in order to get the best answer.

What kind of application are you building? Are you using WebApp Builder/Experience Builder within ArcGIS Online, or are you developing a standalone mapping application on some other stack?

The second description of a GIS layer is relatively accurate. GIS data will (should) have a tabular component that contains attributes related to the point, line, or polygon drawn on the map. The table drives what you see on the map, not the other way around.

I would recommend that you use your organization account or a free ArcGIS Online account and access Esri's "GIS Basics" course [here](https://www.esri.com/training/catalog/5d816c0255cf937306d2d3ef/arcgis-online-basics/) for a great primer on ArcGIS Online, including web layers. There are a number of other free trainings that you can use to enhance your GIS knowledge.